# Arquivo LateX para abrir um arquivo no computador

Tags: pdf, latex, sublime-text

Olá, tenho uma duvida quanto à abertura de arquivos através do PDF.

[Aula 02](https://github.com/CarlosAdir/Algoritmos-em-C/blob/master/Aulas/Aula%2002.pdf) é um arquivo que contém links para abrir outros arquivos. Se eu clico no "1-ola_mundo.c" dentro do pdf, ele deveria abrir o código "Arquivos/1-ola_mundo.c"

Contudo, no meu computador se faço isso, com o Evince dá erro com a mensagem:

```
Unable to open external link
Failed to execute child process "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text" (Permission denied)`
```

Contudo, se eu uso o Okular, ele abre no LibreOffice.

A questão é: quero abrir o código no sublime com qualquer leitor de PDF. Alguma ideia de como conseguir? Reinstalei o sublime-text e o evince e o erro continua.

O arquivo [Aula 02](https://github.com/CarlosAdir/Algoritmos-em-C/blob/master/Aulas/Aula%2002.pdf) fiz em LaTeX com as devidas bibliotecas(`hyperref`) e o código `\href{Arquivos/1-ola\_mundo}{1-ola\_mundo.c}`